# Entering italics in vim

Tags: vim, text-formatting

How does one enter italic text in vim?

In the following screenshot from the [infopage of a certain plugin](https://peterodding.com/code/vim/notes/)
you can see the italic text under the heading Text styles.

[image: example]

It is not my goal to highlight comments in italics as has been asked in many other questions.

I am looking for a keymap by which I can toggle to "italic text mode" and back.

Comment: Please don't cross-post your question to multiple SO sites at the same time. https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14889/entering-italic-text-in-vim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "enter italics", or bold, or underlined. Neither in Vim nor in any other text editor. What you insert is plain characters which get displayed according to their context.

What you see in that screenshot is the effect of a special rule defined in the plugin that tells Vim to italicize text between underscores and "conceal" those underscores. That feature is plugin-specific and can be enabled/disabled with [an option](https://peterodding.com/code/vim/notes/#notes_conceal_italic_option).

Comment: The actual answer portion of this should be more than a two word hyperlink

Answer (score 1):

You can always save your text file in .md format and use [markdown syntax for *italics*](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#emphasis).

For example:

In terminal insert `vim text_file_name.md` to open new text file in vim.

Then in this text file insert some text surrounded with asterixes eg. Some text in * *italics* *.

It should automatically show word "italics" in *italics*.

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla VIM doesn't support this. It's just a text editor. You would need to use a plugin like [Txtfmt](http://www.txtfmt.webs.com/).

Comment: The plugin only seems to support highlighting certain blocks of code in italic, such as comments. It doesn't have a simply toggle switch to *enter in* italics.